Why the text is not vertically aligned with another text in react native on android
I'm encountering an issue with vertically aligning text within a component on Android while using React Native. The text aligns correctly on web platforms, but it's misaligned when rendered on Android devices. I've tried various alignment properties and styles, but haven't been able to achieve the desired vertical positioning.
Android:
"ignore the first one"

Web:

Code:
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import Appbar from "../components/Appbar";
import { Link } from "expo-router";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Appbar/>
      <View style={styles.cardsWrapper}>
        <Link href="/ayat" style={styles.pill}>
          <Text style={styles.emoji}></Text>
          <View style={styles.title}><Text>Happy</Text></View>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/ayat" style={styles.pill}>
          <Text style={styles.emoji}></Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Sad</Text>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/ayat" style={styles.pill}>
          <Text style={styles.emoji}></Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Angry</Text>
        </Link>
    
        <Link href="/ayat" style={styles.pill}>
          <Text style={styles.emoji}></Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Lonely</Text>
        </Link>
    
        <Link href="/ayat" style={styles.pill}>
          <Text style={styles.emoji}></Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Anxious</Text>
        </Link>
    
        <Link href="/ayat" style={styles.pill}>
          <Text style={styles.emoji}></Text>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Thankful</Text>
        </Link>
       </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  cardsWrapper: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    margin: 20,
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  pill: {
    margin: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 99,
    backgroundColor: "#d9bcdf",
    cursor: "pointer"
  },
  emoji: {
    fontSize: 50,
    backgroundColor: "#ff00ff",
    marginRight: 10
  },
  title: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    fontSize: 16,
    backgroundColor: "#ff0000"
  }
});

The text should be vertically aligned with the emoji. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Edit:
I forgot to mention that the marginRight of the emoji is also not working on android and is working fine on web.

Add a container to center items vertically within pill. Something like this:
<Link href="/ayat" style={styles.pill}>
  <View style={styles.pillContainer}>
    <Text style={styles.emoji}></Text>
    <Text style={styles.title}>Happy</Text>
  </View>
</Link>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  pill: {
    margin: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    borderRadius: 99,
    backgroundColor: '#d9bcdf',
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
  pillContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  emoji: {
    fontSize: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ff00ff',
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 16,
    backgroundColor: '#ff0000',
  },
});


Thanks, but why isn't flexbox working as expected in a Link component? It functions correctly in a View component.
